# Programmatically set the un-checked drawable in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a way to programmatically set an un-checked drawable in a BottomNavigationView?

It is possible to set the checked drawable of a tab like this:

`BottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.tab1).setIcon(drawable);`

but I can't find how to set the un-checked version of this tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is not to provide a drawable! But something that acts as a drawable and also knows about the checked and unchecked versions. For that you can use the `StateListDrawable`.

Basically, you define the different states for your drawable; you can give it the different drawable with the corresponding states, like the following:

```kotlin
val uncheckedDrawable = // create your drawable for the unchecked version
val checkedDrawable = // create your drawable for the checked

val stateListDrawable = StateListDrawable()
stateListDrawable.addState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked), checkedDrawable)
stateListDrawable.addState(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked), uncheckedDrawable)
```

And you can use the new `stateListDrawable` with the code you shared like the following:

```kotlin
bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.tab1).setIcon(stateListDrawable);
```

I hope this helps !